# How to include PageFields in HTML when converting using Aspose.Words

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to include a field for the current page number in an HTML string. I was hoping that including the {{PAGE}} token in my string would be enough but it only gets converted to a MailMergeField instead of being replaced with the PageField.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <span style="-aw-field-start:true"></span>
        <span style="-aw-field-code:' PAGE  '"></span>
        <span style="-aw-field-separator:true"></span>
        <span style="-aw-field-end:true"></span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Aspose.Words will convert this HTML into a real PAGE field when using the following code:

```
Document doc = new Document("D:\\temp\\in.html");
doc.Save("D:\\Temp\\out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: This worked great! Your answer also helped me find this page in the documentation which was also a huge help. Thank you!

https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Custom+Styles+used+for+proper+Aspose.Words-HTML-Aspose.Words+Roundtrip